# EO (Essentialobjects) new windows handler error

Tags: c#, .net

I am using EO (Essentialobjects) WebBrowser elmulator,i makin login ,and then i have new windows popup,and i can't handle it.I am new with this EO dll ,and can't find any example of this.

Do any one know how to handle the popUp/Newwindow after i  make event of click.

Here my code:

```
     string loginPostUrl = "https://www.test.com";
      EO.WebBrowser.BrowserOptions op = new EO.WebBrowser.BrowserOptions();
      EO.WebBrowser.Request req = new EO.WebBrowser.Request(loginPostUrl);
      webView1.LoadRequestAndWait(req);

      webView1.EvalScript("document.getElementById('User').value='test'");
      webView1.EvalScript("document.getElementById('Pwd1').value='xxx'");
      webView1.EvalScript("document.getElementById('User').onclick();");

//after click i get error That says i need to handle NewWindows event

    //Itried this but not working
         EO.WebBrowser.DOM.Document doc = webView1.GetDOMWindow().document;
         EO.WebBrowser.NewWindowHandler handler = new 
         NewWindowHandler(WebView_NewWindow);


       public void WebView_NewWindow(object sender, NewWindowEventArgs e)
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about this but here's guess....

```
string info = webView1.EvalScript(@"document.getElementById('User').onclick = (function(event) {return document.getElementById('User').value + '&' + document.getElementById('Pwd1').value});");
```

might get you a string like > "user&Pwd1" wich you can split.

```
string[] array = info.split('&');
string user = array[0];
string pasw = array[1];
```